# Best pratice for using array as the key of memoization in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, memoization

I am doing some algorithm problems in Java, and from time to time the problem needs memoization to optimize speed. And often times, the key is an array. What I usually uses is

```
HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer> mem;
```

The main reason here to use `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `int[]` is that the `hashCode()` of an primitive array is calculated based on the reference, but for `ArrayList<Integer>` the value of the actual array is compared, which is desired behavior.

However, it is not very efficient and code can be pretty lengthy as well. So I am wondering if there is any best practice for this kind of memoization in Java? Thanks.

**UPDATE**: As many have pointed this out in the comments: it is a very bad idea to use mutable objects as the key of a HashMap, which I totally agree.

And I am going to clarify the question a little bit more: when I use this type of memoization, I will NOT change the `ArrayList<Integer>` once it is inserted to the map. Normally the array represents some status, and I need to cache the corresponding value for that status in case it is visited again.

So please do not focus on how bad it is to use a mutable object as the key to a HashMap. Do suggest some better way to do this kind of memoization please.

**UPDATE2**: So at last I choose the `Arrays.toString()` approach since I am doing algorithm problems on TopCoder/Codeforces, and it is just dirty and fast to code.

However, I do think HashMap is the more reasonable and readable way to do this.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to have map keys be mutable.

Comment: Would it make sense to use `HashMap<String, Integer>` and use `Arrays.toString(int[])` as key?

Comment: @arshajii Could you suggest any other way to do this kind of memoization?

Comment: First thought that comes to me is to use a tree-map of integers as the memo.  If it implemented SortedMap, it should do the trick.  TreeMap would work, but you could come up with something more efficient given the constraints on a memo.

Comment: I don't even see how this would work.  Your key is an arrayList which has a different hashCode each time an element is added/removed.  How are you going to get the value if you cannot construct the key?  Unless you want to iterate over the map completely which kind of negates the use of an hashmap.

Comment: As @arshajii pointed out (but not strongly enough), it's a **VERY** bad idea to use mutable objects as keys. If the value of the key is changed, you may not find it in the Map again - not joking, try this: map.put(x,y); change(x); don't be surprised if map.containsKey(x) now returns false; but still, if you iterate through all the map entries, you will still find a key such that x.equals(key). The point I'm trying to make: messing up with keys in maps, may cause the maps to misbehave (contains may return false when they shouldn't, maps can end up with duplicate entries for the same key, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ArrayList` contains usually 3-4 elements,
I would not worry much about performance. Your approach is OK.
But as others pointed out, your key is thus mutable which is
a bad idea.

Another approach is to append all elements of the `ArrayList`
together using some separator (say #) and thus have this kind
of string for key: `123#555#66678` instead of an `ArrayList` of
these 3 integers. You can just call `Arrays.toString(int[])`
and get a decent string key out of an array of integers.

I would choose the second approach.

Comment: The second approach is what I suggested in my comment :)

Comment: Updated with your idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new class - **Key**, put an array with some numbers as a field and implement your own *hascode()* based on the contents of the array.

It will improve the readability as well:

```
HashMap<Key, Integer> mem;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input array is large, the main problem seems to be the efficiency of lookup. On the other hand, your computation is probably much more expensive than that, so you've got same CPU cycles to spare.

Lookup time will depend both on the hashcode calculation *and* on the brute-force `equals` needed to pinpoint the key in a hash bucket. This is why the array as a key is out of the question.

The suggestion already given by user:XpressOneUp, creating a class which wraps the array and provides its custom hash code, seems like your best bet and you can optimize hashcode calculation to involve only some array elements. You'll know best which elements are the most salient.

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the array are small integer than here is way to do it efficiently :-

```
HashMap<String,Integer> Map


public String encode(ArrayList arr) {
 String key = "";
 for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++) {

      key = key + arr.get(i) + ",";
 } 
 return(key);
}
```

Use the encode method to convert your array to unique string use to add and lookup the values in HashMap